# What does "is not recognized as an internal or external command" error mean?

Tags: macos, command-line, xcode, virtualbox

I have spun up a VM of OS X since my main user is not an admin and I need to do things that require admin access.

My end goal is to install the Xcode command line tools into a VirtualBox VM I created with OS X 10.11. Is there a way to do this?

I tried to run `xcode-select --install`, but I got this error:

```
'xcode-select' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or script file
```

But I get the same error (with the command name different) when I ran the `whoami`, `scp`, and `clear` commands. I get an error `No current directory specified` when I run the `ls`, and `cd` commands.

What can I do to narrow down the cause of these terminal errors inside my VM?

Comment: Massive amounts of breakage in that VM. We might need to close this and walk away from it - perhaps asking a follow on question how do I troubleshoot a VM where these 5 commands return the same message - what does "XYZ" error mean. Caleb - can you edit this info into the question: What version of VBOX? What is the guest OS version/build as well as the host OS version and build. `sw_vers` will get you the builds...

Comment: What does "...created with OS X 10.11" mean? Host **and** guest OS are 10.11?

Answer (score 1):

I would spin up a second VM taking careful note of the version of the installer you used to build it up (or document from where you got the VM image). For example, the Install OS X El Capitan installer dated October 12, 2015 installs [build 15B41a of the OS](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201260).

After the first boot, document which command-line tools are broken. You don't need to sign in to the app store or install Xcode to run `xcode-select --install` as that should be bundled with the core OS.

As I commented, massive amounts of breakage is present if the following commands don't run:

- `ls`
- `whoami`

You can run the type command to make sure you at least have a viable set of these commands:

```
mac:~ me$ type ls
ls is /bin/ls
mac:~ me$ type xcode-select
xcode-select is /usr/bin/xcode-select
mac:~ me$ file `which ls`
/bin/ls: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Comment: Same exact issues as before. What do you mean by version of installer?

Comment: @CalebKleveter what did you get for the lines checking ls?

Comment: I asked my brother about the issue, and he asked "Did you log into the VM?". I think my real question, is how do I create and run a VM? I think I'll ask on SuperUser, unless you say here is okay.

Comment: Here is just fine to ask. SU is fine too - just don't ask the exact same question on both sites. That is frowned upon and usually you want to ask a question tailored for the audience on either site.

Comment: @CalebKleveter Also search here as that has probably been asked before

Comment: Here is where I am at now: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/220601/how-do-install-os-x-el-capitan-onto-a-vm