# How do install OS X El Capitan onto a VM

Tags: macos, virtualization, virtualbox

I am spinning up a VM to do some ruby development. At this point I am trying to install OS X 10.11 to it. I have looked into several ways, but they are not working because I have a bad network connection. How is this done?

Here is one link that I looked at: [OS X on OS X](https://ntk.me/2012/09/07/os-x-on-os-x/)

Comment: @user3439894, I jus re-wrote my question.

Comment: After reading the link you included, [OS X on OS X](https://ntk.me/2012/09/07/os-x-on-os-x/), I wouldn't waste one minute trying to use VirtualBox to install OS X El Capitan.  I'd use [VMware Fusion](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion) instead.  It's not free, but you get what you pay for.

Comment: Mmm I think that you can't install a legal OS X on a VM. Is why you have the hackintosh.

Comment: @MrMojoRisin, The Client version of (Mac) OS X has been legally virtualizable since 10.7 and prior to that the Server version since 10.5.    From the current [OS X SLA](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1011.pdf). "_(iii) to install, use and run up to two (2) additional copies or instances of the Apple Software within virtual operating system environments on each Mac Computer you own or control that is already running the Apple Software, for purposes of: (a) software development; (b) testing during software development; (c) using OS X Server; or (d) personal, non- commercial use._"

Comment: @user3439894 ohhh Thanks for your comment :) I'll go to bed a wiser man tonight

Comment: I decided to use Linux because I was having to many issues with OS X. It's working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preface:

This how-to targets VirtualBox because the OP uses it. I strongly recommend to purchase Parallels Desktop or VMware Fusion though. A lot of features like drag-and-drop, <strike>change the monitor resolution</strike> etc. don't work properly in VirtualBox (or I don't get it to work).

---

The installation of El Capitan is a dual-stage process. You first have to create a Yosemite VM and then update to El Capitan.

*The script below apparently doesn't work with El Capitan. A "bootable" El Capitan iso boots to an EFI command line only. The intermediate step of creating a Yosemite.iso seems to be inevitable.*

- Download the latest [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) installer, the latest Yosemite installer and the latest El Capitan installer.
- Install VirtualBox
- Use the following shell script to create a bootable Yosemite.iso. The script assumes that *Install OS X Yosemite.app* was downloaded to the folder /Applications.

  ```
   #!/bin/bash  

   # Create bootable Yosemite ISO

   # Mount the installer image  
   hdiutil attach /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite.app/Contents/SharedSupport/InstallESD.dmg -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/install_app

   # Convert the boot image to a sparse bundle  
   hdiutil convert /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.dmg -format UDSP -o /tmp/Yosemite

   # Increase the sparse bundle capacity to accommodate the packages  
   hdiutil resize -size 8g /tmp/Yosemite.sparseimage

   # Mount the sparse bundle for package addition  
   hdiutil attach /tmp/Yosemite.sparseimage -noverify -nobrowse -mountpoint /Volumes/install_build

   # Remove Package link and replace with actual files  
   rm /Volumes/install_build/System/Installation/Packages
   cp -rp /Volumes/install_app/Packages /Volumes/install_build/System/Installation/

   # Copy Base System  
   cp -rp /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.dmg /Volumes/install_build/
   cp -rp /Volumes/install_app/BaseSystem.chunklist /Volumes/install_build/

   # Unmount the installer image  
   hdiutil detach /Volumes/install_app

   # Unmount the sparse bundle  
   hdiutil detach /Volumes/install_build

   # Resize the partition in the sparse bundle to remove any free space  
   hdiutil resize -size `hdiutil resize -limits /tmp/Yosemite.sparseimage | tail -n 1 | awk '{ print $1 }'`b /tmp/Yosemite.sparseimage

   # Convert the sparse bundle to ISO/CD master  
   hdiutil convert /tmp/Yosemite.sparseimage -format UDTO -o /tmp/Yosemite

   # Remove the sparse bundle  
   rm /tmp/Yosemite.sparseimage

   # Rename the ISO and move it to the desktop  
   mv /tmp/Yosemite.cdr ~/Desktop/Yosemite.iso
  ```

  Copy the above lines, paste it into a new document *prepare_yosemite_iso.sh* on your desktop with a decent editor (below I use *nano*) and make it executable. In Terminal enter:

  ```
  touch ~/Desktop/prepare_yosemite_iso.sh
  nano ~/Desktop/prepare_yosemite_iso.sh #paste the content of the script here, save the file to disk with ctrl-O and quit nano with ctrl-X
  chmod +x ~/Desktop/prepare_yosemite_iso.sh
  ```
- execute the script:

  ```
  ~/Desktop/prepare_yosemite_iso.sh
  ```

  After several minutes the iso with the name *Yosemite.iso* will be moved to your desktop.
- Start VirtualBox and create a new Yosemite VM with the default settings.
- If your Mac contains a Haswell processor you have to change the the *cpuid* in the VM. Enter the following in Terminal:

  ```
  VBoxManage list vms #to list all available VMs
  VBoxManage modifyvm <name_of_vm> --cpuidset 00000001 000306a9 00020800 80000201 178bfbff
  ```
- Attach *Yosemite.iso* to the optical drive
- Boot the VM, format the hdd, then install and configure Yosemite.
- Copy the downloaded *Install OS X El Capitan.app* to the Applications folder in the VM. Use a network share on the host to accomplish that.
- Start *Install OS X El Capitan.app* and update the VM to El Capitan.
- To enable some screen resolutions shut down the VM and enter in (the host's) Terminal:

  ```
  VBoxManage setextradata <name_of_vm> VBoxInternal2/EfiGopMode N
  ```

  where N can be one of 0,1,2,3,4,5 referring to the 640x480, 800x600, 1024x768, 1280x1024, 1440x900, 1920x1200  screen resolution respectively
- Do **Ruby** development...

Comment: FWIW, my reason for switching from VirtualBox to VMware Fusion was strictly due to performance.  VirtualBox is well-supported and seems to work very well, but it's much slower than Fusion in my experience.

Comment: @EmmEff Hmm El C. boots in 28 seconds to the desktop using VBox. In Parallels 10.9 needs 39s, 10.8 41s etc and 10.10 is even slower. But I'm restricted to 1024x768  in VBox and a lot of features I'm used to aren't available.

Comment: Boot time is an irrelevant measure of system performance and I was speaking of VMware Fusion, not Parallels.  If you're happy with VirtualBox, then use it.  I was simply commenting that VirtualBox is not the fastest solution.

Comment: @EmmEff I'm using Parallels/VMware. But the OP needed a solution for VirtualBox. In my answer I recommended Parallels or VMware.

Answer (score -1):

It is very easy to install all the Mac OS versions like Mavericks, Yosemite, and El Capitan on VMware workstations 11.
Due to lengthy tutorial, I suggest you to read the complete article from [here](http://kecodoc.com/install-os-x-yosemiteel-capitan-on-vmware-workstation-11-in-windows/).
Feel free to ask me any question if you face problem during installation.

Comment: The question - though not very obvious - targets VirtualBox. We all know that installing newer OS Xs in Parallels or VMware is more convenient than in VirtualBox.